# Excel VBA macro OLEObjects.add issues

Tags: excel, vba

EDIT:

I started a new workbook and tore down the original code to test in a fresh environment. None of the OLEObjects.add methods seem to work even in this sanitized environment. I'm beginning to think that this method and parameters fundamentally do something other than what I think they do based on their [documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.oleobjects.add) I've included the parsed down code below along with a picture of what attaching a .pdf file looks like.

```
Sub AttachDocument()
'create cell location string

Dim celllocation As String
celllocation = ("D6")

'Select the cell in which you want to place the attachment

Range(celllocation).Select

'Get file path
'fpath = Application.GetOpenFilename("All Files,*.*", Title:="Select file")
'If LCase(fpath) = "false" Then Exit Sub
fpath = "C:\Users\Username\Desktop\2019W2.pdf"

'Insert file
Worksheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects.Add Filename:=fpath, Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=True, IconFileName:="EXCEL.EXE"
End Sub
```

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

I just don't understand why the parameters do not work. Any help is appreciated.

Original Post:

I have code that adds an OLEObject to a worksheet at a specific cell.  It works, but I cannot get the parameters for OLEObjects.add method to do anything.  The only one that seems to work is "Filename". No matter how I define any of the other parameters the behavior of the macro does not change; I'm not even sure the "Linked" parameter is working and the icon is always dependent on the file type uploaded but does not behave as expected(e.g. word documents do not display word icon, instead a large blank/white square). Ultimately, I want to set the icon to a common icon and define its size. What am I doing wrong here?

```
Sub AttachDocument()

    'Check to make sure there is a selection for table row, if not end macro, also check for selection greater than the number of rows in the table, if yes end macro
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("RenewablesTable")
    If Range("M3").Value < 1 Then
    ElseIf Range("M3").Value > tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count Then
    Else

        'create cell location string

        Dim cellnum As Integer, celllocation As String
        cellnum = Range("M3").Value + 8
        celllocation = ("M" & cellnum)

        'Select the cell in which you want to place the attachment

        Range(celllocation).Select

        'check if cell already has an object if it does end macro
        If CheckCellforObject(celllocation) > 0 Then

        Else
            'Get file path
            fpath = Application.GetOpenFilename("All Files,*.*", Title:="Select file")
            If LCase(fpath) = "false" Then Exit Sub

            'Insert file
            Worksheets("Renewable Energy").Unprotect "password"
            Worksheets("Renewable Energy").OLEObjects.Add Filename:=fpath, Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=True, IconFileName:="excel.exe"
            Worksheets("Renewable Energy").Protect "password"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Try creating the `OLEObject` in a test sub on a test worksheet, i.e. an unprotected worksheet with a hard-coded `fpath` string. Make sure you can get that to work first, then back it into your business logic. If it doesn't work in your business logic, it probably has something to do with the variables being formed. So put in some temporary `Debug.Print` statements to see what's going on.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I can get the object created, and it appears in my worksheet. The issue is that the various parameters don't seem to be doing anything. I change the icon and it ignores it and puts whatever icon it wants, which is usually a large blank white box. I have tried it on the sheet unprotected and it does the same.  I will try to recreate on a fresh workbook and see if I can get the parameters to work, then go form there.

Comment: You may have to fully specify the path `IconFileName:="C:\Your\Path\excel.exe`

Comment: Thanks Chris.  I have tried various full file paths to various icon files.  It never works. The code example above is just the most recent attempt.